# LINQ: How to select one column after Any() method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to select `DeviceTypeID` from the below query but I can't because I started my query with `.Any()` method. Please help me to select `DeviceTypeID`

```
var Ids = query.Any(a => a.HospitalDepartments.Any(b => 
                        b.Units.Any(c => c.Devices.Select(f => f.DeviceTypeID)))).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `Any()`? What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Any` checks if there is at least one item in the collection that meets a predicate. From how it looks what you want is a way to collect all the `DeviceTypeID`s in all your hierarchy. If so, then you need `SelectMany`:

```
var ids = query.SelectMany(a => 
              a.HospitalDepartments.SelectMany(b => 
                  b.Units.SelectMany(c => 
                      c.Devices.Select(f => f.DeviceTypeID)))).ToList();
```

Comment: It's working very well! Thank you so much. 
Can please kindly please help me to solve this problem .... i am you are smart enough to solve it!

Here is my question link:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430023/linq-how-to-use-the-exact-array-value-instead-of-contains)