# How to use the Exact array value instead of Contains

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I need to use Equals method or something similar instead of using Contains method because i want to search in database for the exact values in `selectedDeviceTypeIDs` array not any of it.

```
IEnumerable<Guid> selectedDeviceTypeIDs = DeviceTypeIDs
    .Split(',')
    .Select( Guid.Parse )
    .AsEnumerable();

query = query
    .Where( j =>
        j.HospitalDepartments.Any( jj =>
            jj.Units.Any( m =>
                m.Devices.Any( w =>
                    selectedDeviceTypeIDs.Contains( w.DeviceTypeID )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Here is my full code

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAvailableHospitalsByAjax(System.Guid? DirectorateOfHealthID = null, System.Guid? UnitTypeID = null, string DeviceTypeIDs = null)
{
    Context db = new Context();
    var query = db.Hospitals.AsQueryable();

    if (DeviceTypeIDs != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<Guid> selectedDeviceTypeIDs = DeviceTypeIDs.Split(',').Select(Guid.Parse).AsEnumerable();
        query = query.Where(j => j.HospitalDepartments.Any(jj => jj.Units.Any(m => m.Devices.Any(w => selectedDeviceTypeIDs.Contains(w.DeviceTypeID)))));
    }

    if (UnitTypeID != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(j => j.HospitalDepartments.Any(www => www.Units.Any(u => u.UnitTypeID == UnitTypeID)));
    }

    if (DirectorateOfHealthID != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(h => h.DirectorateHealthID == DirectorateOfHealthID);
    }

    query = query.Where(j => j.HospitalDepartments.Any(u => u.Units.Any(d => d.Devices.Any(s => s.Status == Enums.DeviceStatus.Free)))
    && j.HospitalDepartments.Any(hd => hd.Units.Any(u => u.Beds.Any(b => b.Status == Enums.BedStatus.Free))));

    var list = query.ToList();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, list);
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is.  What do you mean by "exact values"?  Can you give an example of the contents and what you expect the results to be?

Comment: Side note - the `.AsEnumerable()` is redundant  - it is already an `IEnumerable`

Comment: You need to join then. `from record in db from x in arr where ... select ...`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not `Contains()` but with the `Any()` method used in your query which will return **true** immediately after it finds a device whose `DeviceTypeID` is in the provided `selectedDeviceTypeIDs` list.

If you need to check if all the devices of a unit match all the items in the list, you could use:

```
query = query
.Where(j =>
    j.HospitalDepartments.Any(jj =>
        jj.Units.Any(m =>
            m.Devices.All(
                w => selectedDeviceTypeIDs.Contains(w.DeviceTypeID))
            &&
            selectedDeviceTypeIDs.All(
                g => m.Devices.Select(d => d.DeviceTypeID).Contains(g))
        )
    )
);
```

Note that if you have duplicate items in the `selectedDeviceTypeIDs` but not in the `Devices` of the `Unit`, it will still return true.